# Como separar os caracteres de uma string para lista em Python?

Tags: python, string

Como posso converter uma string (uma palavra, por exemplo) em lista?

```
entrada:
a='carro'
saída:
['c', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'o']
```

Sei que, usando `split`, transforma em lista fica a palavra toda, gostaria de saber se como uma palavra especifica virar lista.

Comment: é só chamar o construtor da lista, passando a string desejada. Cmo strings também são squências de strings de comprimento 1, é exatamente o que acontece: `list(a)` -> `['c', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'o']`

Answer (score 13):

Desta forma retorna uma lista com os caracteres em cada posição

```
list(a)
```

Veja em funcionamento no [Coding Ground](http://tpcg.io/wC0Q5k)

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/346981/112052), existem alguns casos em que usar somente `list` pode não ser o suficiente. Veja este exemplo:

```
print(list('pá'))
print(list('pá'))
```

Apesar de não parecer, as duas linhas acima são diferentes, pois este código imprime o seguinte:

```
['p', 'á']
['p', 'a', '́']
```

<sup>***Obs**: se for testar o código acima, copie e cole, pois se você digitar diretamente, pode não dar o efeito desejado. Mais detalhes sobre isso ao longo da resposta.*</sup>

Isso acontece porque, de maneira **bem** resumida, o [Unicode](https://unicode.org/main.html) define duas formas de representar a letra "a" com acento agudo:

1. composta - como o code point [U+00E1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e1) (á)
2. decomposta - como uma combinação de dois code points (nesta ordem):

   - a letra "a" (sem acento): [U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061)
   - o acento agudo: [U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301)

A primeira forma é chamada de NFC, e a segunda, NFD. Para mais detalhes sobre normalização, o que é um code point, etc, veja [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052). No caso, na primeira linha do código acima, a string está em NFC, e na segunda linha, está em NFD (o terceiro elemento da lista é o próprio caractere "acento agudo" - que dependendo de como for renderizado, pode aparecer quase "grudado" nas aspas de fechamento, ficando quase imperceptível - e repare que o segundo elemento é a letra "a" sem acento).

O detalhe é que ao ser mostrado na tela, ambas as formas NFC e NFD acabam sendo renderizadas da mesma forma, por isso não há diferença aparente nas duas linhas do código acima - ambos mostram a letra "á" (e por isso você deve copiar e colar o código acima para testar, pois se tentar digitar diretamente pelo teclado, ele preferencialmente escolherá apenas umas das formas e as linhas acabarão ficando idênticas).

E o que acontece é que [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), ao receber um iterável, constrói uma lista na qual cada elemento do iterável se torna um elemento da lista. E strings são iteráveis em Python, e ao iterar por uma string, na verdade estamos iterando pelos code points dela. Por isso há esta diferença, caso a string esteja em NFD.

E como não foi especificado de onde vêm as strings, esta é uma situação que pode acontecer, pois os dados podem vir de um arquivo, requisição HTTP, o usuário copiou e colou de algum lugar que estava em NFD (mas como é renderizado da mesma forma, não percebeu a diferença), etc. Ou seja, isso pode acontecer sem você se dar conta (como aconteceu, por exemplo, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/467835/112052)).

---

#### Como resolver?

Para textos simples - especialmente se estiverem em português - bastaria normalizar para NFC:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

print(list(normalize('NFC', 'pá')))
```

Assim eu garanto que, mesmo que a string esteja em NFD, os caracteres "a sem acento" e "acento" serão "juntados" em um só (o "á").

Vale lembrar que isso não fica restrito à língua portuguesa e também funciona para outros tipos de "caracteres":

```
# sim, um emoji direto no código (emojis também tem code points definidos pelo Unicode, então funciona da mesma forma)
print(list(normalize('NFC', '堆積'))) # ['', '堆', '積']
```

Mas nem sempre isso funciona, claro. Nem todos os caracteres do mundo possuem um correspondente em NFC, e nem sempre a normalização para NFC produzirá um único code point. Ex:

```
from unicodedata import normalize

s = 'ẛ̣'
# mesmo normalizando em NFC, ainda resulta em dois code points
print(list(normalize('NFC', s))) # ['ẛ', '̣']
```

Ou ainda:

```
# emoji de família
s = ''.join(map(chr, [0x1f468, 0x200d, 0x1f469, 0x200d, 0x1f467, 0x200d, 0x1f467]))
print(s) # se seu browser for compatível, mostrará a família ‍‍‍
print(list(normalize('NFC', s))) # ['', '\u200d', '', '\u200d', '', '\u200d', '']
```

Emojis de família são na verdade formados por vários emojis diferentes, unidos por um [Zero Width Joiner](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) (o `\u200d` mostrado acima). Então mesmo se normalizarmos para NFC, ainda sim a lista resultante terá os code points separados.

E isso não se aplica somente a emojis, existem caracteres de outros alfabetos que possuem a mesma característica (são formados por mais de um code point, e mesmo normalizando para NFC, continuam com mais de um):

```
print(list(normalize('NFC', 'नु'))) # ['न', 'ु']
```

Esse conjunto de code points que juntos formam "uma coisa só" são chamados de [Grapheme Clusters](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/). **Caso o objetivo seja ter uma lista de Grapheme Clusters** (já que os code points destes, separadamente, não têm exatamente o mesmo significado), não há uma forma direta de fazer, e o jeito é recorrer a bibliotecas externas.

Um exemplo é o [módulo `grapheme`](https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/):

```
# Atenção: módulo não-nativo - Instale em https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/
from grapheme import graphemes

def to_list(s):
    return list(graphemes(s))

# emoji de família
s = ''.join(map(chr, [0x1f468, 0x200d, 0x1f469, 0x200d, 0x1f467, 0x200d, 0x1f467]))
print(to_list(s)) # ['\u200d\u200d\u200d']
print(to_list('नु')) # ['नु']
```

A diferença, claro, é que nem sempre os elementos da lista terão apenas um code point. Mas isso é porque, graças a todas as possibilidades que o Unicode nos traz, a definição de "caractere" passou a ser mais complexa. Um emoji é um caractere (no sentido de ser "um único símbolo mostrado na tela, que possui significado próprio")? E o `á` em NFD, apesar de ter dois code points, é mostrado como um único caractere, então será aceitável ter mais de um code point em cada elemento da lista? Ou eu quero uma lista na qual cada elemento é um code point, independente da normalização?

Para uma discussão mais aprofundada, visite o [link já citado](/a/396555/112052), mas de qualquer forma, a solução "correta" depende do que você precisa (se seu texto não terá grapheme clusters, por exemplo, não precisaria se preocupar com esta última parte, bastando normalizar para NFC - cada caso é um caso).

Comment: cara, 
eu gosto de resposta informativas e completas. Mas nesse caso, a pessoa perguntou como chegar na padaria da esquina, e você deu todas as formas de fazer isso, inclusive de avião e transatlântico (vá até uma cidade portuária, compre uma passagem de cruzeiro). 
Acho que o bom senso tem que prevalecer - nesse caso, valeria a pena formular uma pergunta digna desta resposta - envolvendo a questão de unicode, e grapheme clusters _na questão_ - aí você cola essa mesma resposta lá: acho que seria mais construtivo.
A resposta aqui é `list(a)`  e acabou.

Comment: (par ilustrar, a minha resposta com mais votos no S.O. em inglês é justamente uma desse tipo, onde se pergunta 'como contar ocorrências de uma substring dentro de uma string`) e eu respondo em 3 linhas pra usar o método `.count`. Eu tenho uma resposta mais completa na mesma pergunta (para substrings que façam overlap) - mas deixo numa resposta separada - é um caso em que o bom senso diz que a resposta simples vai ajudar mais de 90% das pessoas que cairem lá)

Comment: @jsbueno A pergunta fala em "separar os caracteres de uma string", sem especificar o que pode ter na string (claro que no exemplo dado tem uma string simples, mas eu achei importante enfatizar que strings não se limitam a isso e generalizei para "qualquer coisa"). Até porque muitos nem sequer concebem a possibilidade de existir essas coisas que menciono na resposta, e por isso achei válido mostrar isso. A resposta para o exemplo específico da pergunta pode ser `list(a)`, mas se considerar o título (que não especifica nada), eu acho válido falar de Unicode e tudo mais...

Comment: ...pois aí a definição de "caractere" passa a não ser tão clara, e "separar os caracteres" pode ter várias possibilidades, e a solução correta vai depender de cada caso. Concordo que **talvez** teria sido melhor outra pergunta mais específica, mas meu receio é que acabasse fechada como dup, então no fim preferi responder aqui mesmo.

Comment: essa definição de caracter é assunto para dois (e não um só) capitulo de livro - é fácil ver que não é o que está preocupando o A.P.. 

E não seria "dup" - a pergunta com foco em entender o que é um caractere unicode e como são as sequências é muito mais ampla do que essa, inclusive extapolando a linguagem de programação. O que você escreveu aqui é algo que dá pra afirar que 95% dos devs desconhecem, e é muito importante - mas é um tópico mais avançado do que "como separar os caracteres de uma string em uma lista" - quando o exemplo do AP sequer inclui caracteres acentuados.

Comment: @jsbueno o exemplo apresentado tem seu mérito e não pode ser ignorado do ponto de vista de processamento de caracteres: `print(len(list('pá')) != len(list('pá')))`

Comment: @jsbueno Sempre achei muitas respostas suas excelentes justamente por serem mais que um "tente isso" e irem além do que foi perguntado. É isso que tentei fazer aqui, lembrando que o conteúdo deve ser útil para qualquer um, não somente o AP - por isso acho irrelevante se ele estava preocupado ou não com as implicações do Unicode (e já que estamos especulando o que ele quer/pensa, vai que ele está nos 95% que vc citou, e por isso não mencionou nada na pergunta - pois ele nem imaginava que isso pudesse existir) :-) Na verdade não importa, as respostas não devem servir apenas ao AP...

Comment: Se vamos discutir como separar os caracteres de uma string, eu acho relevante sim apontar (mesmo que superficialmente) que a definição de "caractere" pode não ser tão simples assim. Não tinha a pretensão de esgotar o assunto (que de fato precisa de um livro para tal) mas pelo menos de mencionar que isso existe e quem quiser, pode procurar mais informações - para isso coloquei links pra outras perguntas, que por sua vez tem links para muitas outras fontes (este será meu último comentário aqui, mas se quiser, podemos continuar no meta)

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim converter uma string em uma lista. Para isso, basta passar a string como parâmetro da lista.
O código abaixo recebe uma string qualquer e a converte em uma lista.

```
a = list(input('Digite uma palavra: '))
print('A lista criada é: {}'.format(a))
```

Este código recebe qualquer string e, em seguida, a converte para uma lista.

Comment: É isso mesmo Augusto. Me empolguei com a resposta e esqueci deste detalhe. Por padrão, no Python, tudo recebido pelo input é convertido em string automaticamente, a menos que se converta a um outro tipo (int, float, etc). Agora sim, o algoritmo está perfeito.

Comment: Qual a diferença para o que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/346981/69296) apresentou?

Comment: @Luiz Felipe, boa noite. A diferença foi que a minha resposta é mais generalizada, uma vez que esta captura qualquer string, em vez de trabalhar com apenas  a palavra `carro`.

Comment: A outra resposta também funciona pra qualquer string. Ela só não colocou o `input`, mas na verdade isso nem faz diferença, pois a string poderia vir de qualquer lugar (`input`, arquivo, requisição HTTP, etc), que a solução seria a mesma: usar `list`. Sendo assim, de fato não há diferença para a outra resposta...

Comment: @hkotsubo, boa noite! Obrigado ....  e, obrigado pela observação.  A minha intensão é de compartilhar conhecimento.  Não estou aqui competindo com ninguém. Abraço.

Comment: Não é questão de competir, e sim de ter respostas redundantes (o que não acrescenta ao site, pois a ideia não é ter várias respostas com basicamente a mesma solução). Novas respostas são bem vindas, desde que mostre outras formas de fazer, o que não foi o caso aqui (pois usar `list` já foi sugerido na outra resposta, e o fato de ter colocado `input` não torna esta diferente, dado que a solução no fim é a mesma)

Comment: @hkotsubo, entendi completamente seu posicionamento e intenção.  Estou aqui com a mesma intenção de vocês. Vou procurar quintuplicar meu desempenho. Paz à todos.

Comment: Pode ainda usar outra sintaxe em sua resposta o unpack `print([*"Hello World"])`.