# Regex não está verificando o caractere acentuado, mesmo tendo ele na expressão

Tags: python, string, regex

Possuo a seguinte regex em Python para filtrar a entrada de texto da minha aplicação:

```
import re
good_chars_regexp = re.compile(r"^[A-Za-záéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ00-9\,\.\-\?\"\'\’\!\“\s\;\:\“\”\–\‘\’\’\/\\]+$", re.IGNORECASE)
```

Portanto, frases como: `'Olá amigos da Internet!'` e `'Dúvida sobre Python'` devem passar.

Quando realizo a seguinte verificação:

```
lista = ['Olá amigos da Internet!', 'Dúvida sobre Python', '@StackOverFlow']
for l in lista:
    print(re.match(good_chars_regexp, l) is not None)
```

Tenho como retorno: `False`, `True`, `False`. A primeira frase: `'Olá amigos da Internet!'` deveria retornar `True`.

A intenção da minha regex é permitir palavras com acento, números e os caracteres especiais que especifiquei, como `!`, `?`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você caiu na "pegadinha do [Unicode](https://unicode.org/)"! Mas vamos por partes.

---

Primeiro, eu copiei e colei a palavra `Olá` do seu código e fiz o seguinte:

```
from unicodedata import name
for s in 'Olá': # para cada caractere da string
    print(f'{s} {ord(s):4X} {name(s)}')
```

Ou seja, para cada caractere da string, imprimo o próprio caractere, o [seu code point](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) e o seu [*Unicode name*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.name). O resultado foi:

```
O   4F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
l   6C LATIN SMALL LETTER L
a   61 LATIN SMALL LETTER A
́  301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
```

Sim, 4 caracteres, e o último é o [acento agudo](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm).

O que acontece é que esta string está na forma NFD (uma das [formas de normalização definidas pelo Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)). Para entender em detalhes, sugiro que leia [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052), mas resumindo, o caractere `á` (letra "a" com acento agudo) pode ser representado de duas formas:

- como um único caractere: o `á` ([LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm))
- como uma combinação de 2 caracteres: [a letra "a"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm) (sem acento) e o acento agudo (o quarto caractere que aparece no exemplo acima)

A primeira forma é conhecida como NFC, e a segunda, como NFD (leia os links já sugeridos acima para saber mais).

O problema é que ambas as formas, quando renderizadas, são mostradas na tela - na grande maioria das fontes, senão em "todas" - do mesmo jeito, e você só percebe a diferença se "escovar os bits" e verificar o que de fato tem na string. Sendo assim, a regex não vai dar *match* nesta string porque o acento não foi incluído na lista de caracteres válidos.

Uma alternativa para resolver é converter a string para NFC, usando [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize). Assim a letra "a" e o acento são combinados no caractere `á`:

```
from unicodedata import name, normalize
for s in normalize('NFC', 'Olá'):
    print(f'{s} {ord(s):4X} {name(s)}')
```

Veja a diferença:

```
O   4F LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
l   6C LATIN SMALL LETTER L
á   E1 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
```

---

Outro detalhe é que dentro de colchetes, [vários caracteres não precisam ser escapados com `\`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special). E como você usou a [*flag* `re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE), não precisa colocar maiúsculas e minúsculas na expressão, pois a *flag* já irá considerar ambas (ou seja, pode deixar a regex somente com as minúsculas - ou somente com as maiúsculas).

E a expressão compilada (retornada por [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)) também possui o [método `match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match), que você pode usar diretamente (em vez de `re.match(good_chars_regexp, etc)`, pode fazer somente `good_chars_regexp.match(etc)`):

```
import re

lista = ['Olá amigos da Internet!', 'Dúvida sobre Python', '@StackOverFlow']
good_chars_regexp = re.compile(r"^[a-záéíóúâêîôãõç0-9,.\-?\"'’!“\s;:“”\–‘’’/\\]+$", re.IGNORECASE)

from unicodedata import normalize

for l in lista:
    print(good_chars_regexp.match(normalize('NFC', l)) is not None)
```

A saída é:

```
True
True
False
```

---

Se quiser instalar um módulo externo, uma alternativa é o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), que tem algumas funcionalidades a mais do que o módulo `re`. Um que pode ajudar neste caso é o [suporte a *Unicode properties*](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#unicode-codepoint-properties-including-scripts-and-blocks):

```
import regex
good_chars_regexp = regex.compile(r"^([0-9,.\-?\"'’!“\s;:“”\–‘’’/\\]|\p{Script=Latin}\p{M}?)+$", regex.IGNORECASE)
for l in lista: # não precisa mais normalizar
    print(good_chars_regexp.match(l) is not None)
```

Assim, a regex considera números e demais caracteres (ponto, vírgula, hífen, aspas, etc), **ou** `\p{Script=Latin}\p{M}?`.

No caso `\p{Script=Latin}` são todos os caracteres [desta lista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) (que talvez seja abrangente demais caso só queira textos em português) e `\p{M}` inclui as categorias "Mark" (todas que começam com "M" [desta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)), na qual o acento agudo se inclui. O `?` logo depois indica que é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (ou seja, podemos ter apenas a letra, ou letra seguida do acento, no caso da string estar em NFD).

---

Obs: Vale lembrar também que esta regex não verifica se tem palavras de fato. Por exemplo, se a string for `!!!,,,"  "`, ela considera válida. Claro que aí já foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta, mas se a ideia for, por exemplo, verificar que tem pelo menos uma letra ou algo assim, talvez ajude dar uma olhada [aqui](/q/342605/112052), [aqui](/q/337924/112052) e [aqui](/q/377860/112052).

---

Por fim, uma opção - um pouco mais complicada - que funciona independente da string estar em NFC ou NFD, e que não exige normalização, seria:

```
good_chars_regexp = re.compile(r"^([a-záéíóúâêîôãõç0-9,.\-?\"'’!“\s;:“”\–‘’’/\\]|[aeiou]\u0301|[aeio]\u0302|[ao]\u0303|c\u0327)+$", re.IGNORECASE)
```

No caso, eu considero as letras acentuadas (`áéí...`), ou as letras seguidas do respectivo acento - e para isso eu usei os escapes unicode (`\u` seguido do código hexadecimal de cada caractere), usando os códigos do [acento agudo](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm), [circunflexo](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/302/index.htm), [til](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/303/index.htm) e [cedilha](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/327/index.htm) (cada um precedido das respectivas letras que podem tê-los). Assim, a regex pega tanto os casos em NFC quanto em NFD.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Muito completa e cheia de referências!