# Como fazer o Python tratar diacríticos como parte de um caractere?

Tags: python, unicode

Eu estou tentando separar a palavra "wɨoɾɨ̃mɨ" em sílabas. Ou seja, o output deve ser ["wɨ", "o", "ɾɨ̃", "mɨ"].

A função que está separando as palavras em sílabas procura uma vogal e recorta o trecho até essa vogal como uma sílaba.

```
def syllabification(word):
    vowels = ["ɨ̃", "õ", "i", "ɨ", "ã", "ĩ", "á", "u", "í", "ó", "o", "e", "ẽ", "ú", "ũ", "é", "a"]
    syllables = []
    new_word = word[:]
    while new_word != "":
        found_vowel = False
        for i, letter in enumerate(new_word):
            if letter in vowels:
                syllables.append(new_word[:i+1])
                new_word = new_word[i+1:]
                found_vowel = True
                break
            else:
                continue
        if not found_vowel:
            break

    return syllables
```

No entanto, o item "ɨ̃" não é considerado um caractere único, mas um caractere "ɨ" seguido por um diacrítico tilde. Dessa forma, o output que eu recebo é ['wɨ', 'o', 'ɾɨ', '̃mɨ'].

Eu tentei criar condições em que o próximo caractere é um tilde combinável e fazer o recorte se alongar até depois dele, mas o output continua sendo o mesmo.

Existe alguma forma de tratar essa combinação de caracteres como um só?

Comment: Talvez seja melhor tratar os grapheme clusters em vez de caracteres individuais, dá pra usar o [módulo `grapheme`](https://pypi.org/project/grapheme/) - tem um exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/497877/112052). Ou procure por módulos que já possuem a funcionalidade de separar sílabas, como o pyphen ou NLTK.